# Custom Controller.cs.t4 only works when wrong

Tags: c#, visual-studio, t4

I have copied the T4 scaffolding templates into my Visual Studio 2017 project so I can customize them. Mostly it's working fine.  But one line in Controller.cs.t4 is causing a headache.
This problematic line needs to be like this for scaffolding to work:

```
var entitySetVar = EntitySetVariable ?? (String.IsNullOrEmpty(entitySetName) ? entitySetName : (entitySetName.Substring(0, length:1).ToLowerInvariant() + entitySetName.Substring(1)));
```

And it has to be like this for the project to build:

```
var entitySetVar = EntitySetVariable ?? (String.IsNullOrEmpty(entitySetName) ? entitySetName : (entitySetName.Substring(0, length-1).ToLowerInvariant() + entitySetName.Substring(1)));
```

Note the difference: length:1  vs  length-1

With length:1 I get syntax errors immediately, but scaffolding works fine.

With length-1, no syntax errors, but scaffolding fails saying: "Compiling transformation: The name 'length' does not exist in the current context' at line number '54' and column number '127'"

Can someone explain what is going on and/or suggest a fix? Switching back and forth is getting old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the Length property of the string like this:

```
var entitySetVar = EntitySetVariable ?? (String.IsNullOrEmpty(entitySetName) ? entitySetName : (entitySetName.Substring(0, entitySetName.Length-1).ToLowerInvariant() + entitySetName.Substring(1)));
```

Answer (score 1):

So to start the operator `:1` and `-1` are fundamentally **not** the same thing. 
The `:` operator is a bit of a strange one and I've not found much use in it, but I admit it has it's place.

The `:` operator is used when you want to specify a particular parameter into a method, say for example we have a method that looks something like this:

```
void DoSomething(int numberOne = 0, int numberTwo = 0, int numberThree = 0)
```

And we wanted to use this method for something but change `numberThree`'s value without specifying `numberOne` or `numberTwo` then this can be achieved through the `:` operator as such:

```
DoSomething(numberThree: 3);
```

See what I did? I specified the parameter `numberThree` and passed in the number `3`. I could also do:

DoSomething(0,0,3);

More information on this here:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments

The `-` is a little more simple to explain as it is a maths function, subtract

```
3-1=2
```

The when using variables, we have to assign a variable name to a value:

```
var length = 1
```

before we use it:

```
 length-1
```

The answer to the second question

```
var entitySetVar = EntitySetVariable ?? (String.IsNullOrEmpty(entitySetName) ? entitySetName : (entitySetName.Substring(0, length-1).ToLowerInvariant() + entitySetName.Substring(1)));
```

Is simple, you have not set the variable `length` a value, you can do so like:

```
var length = 1;
var entitySetVar = EntitySetVariable ?? (String.IsNullOrEmpty(entitySetName) ? entitySetName : (entitySetName.Substring(0, length-1).ToLowerInvariant() + entitySetName.Substring(1)));
```

That should now compile.

As for the first example:

```
var entitySetVar = EntitySetVariable ?? (String.IsNullOrEmpty(entitySetName) ? entitySetName : (entitySetName.Substring(0, length:1).ToLowerInvariant() + entitySetName.Substring(1)));
```

that should work fine as is

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation. It led me to the solution.